# Mongodb unwind array nested in array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

This is my collection:

```
db.questions.insertMany([
  {
    "content": [
      {
        "languageId": "en",
        "text": "What are you planning to buy today at the supermarket?"
      },
      {
        "languageId": "nl",
        "text": "Wat ben je van plan om vandaag in de supermarkt te kopen?"
      },
    ],
    "type": "multipleChoice",
    "multipleChoice": {
      "numAnswers": { "min": 1, "max": 1 },
      "possibleAnswers": [
        {
          "sequence": 1,
          "content": [
            {
              "languageId": "en",
              "text": "apples"
            },
            {
              "languageId": "nl",
              "text": "appels"
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          "sequence": 2,
          "content": [
            {
              "languageId": "en",
              "text": "peers"
            },
            {
              "languageId": "nl",
              "text": "peren"
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    }
  },
  {
    "content": [
      {
        "languageId": "en",
        "text": "How do you feel?"
      },
      {
        "languageId": "nl",
        "text": "Hoe voel je je?"
      },
    ],
    "type": "ranking1to5",
  }
]);
```

I want to transform into one language that are in two `content` arrays. So I want to have the output:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5abe4c09d3831890de28ec8f"),
    "content" : 
        {
            "languageId" : "en",
            "text" : "What are you planning to buy today at the supermarket?"
        }, 
    "type" : "multipleChoice",
    "multipleChoice" : {
        "numAnswers" : {
            "min" : 1.0,
            "max" : 1.0
        },
        "possibleAnswers" : [ 
            {
                "sequence" : 1.0,
                "content" : 
                    {
                        "languageId" : "en",
                        "text" : "apples"
                    }
            }, 
            {
                "sequence" : 2.0,
                "content" :  
                    {
                        "languageId" : "en",
                        "text" : "peers"
                    }
            }
        ]
    }
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5abe4c09d3831890de28ec90"),
    "content" :  
        {
            "languageId" : "en",
            "text" : "How do you feel?"
        },
    "type" : "ranking1to5"
}
```

I tried using `$unwind`, `$match` and `$group` to tackle this problem. I have come pretty far only the last piece does not work:

```
db.getCollection('questions').aggregate([
    { $unwind: "$content" },
    { $match: { "content.languageId": "en" } },
    { $unwind: { path: '$multipleChoice.possibleAnswers', preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true } },
    { $unwind: { path: '$multipleChoice.possibleAnswers.content', preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true } },
    { $match: { "multipleChoice.possibleAnswers.content.languageId": "en" } },
    { $group: { _id: "$_id", content: { $first: "$content" }, type: { $first: "$type" }, multipleChoice: { $addToSet: "$multipleChoice" } } }
])
```

The problem is `multipleChoice` gets repeated while this should be `possibleAnswers`. Also the question that has no `multipleChoice` object should be included.

Any help is particularly appreciated !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a good fit for the `$redact`. Please try the following aggregation:

```
db.questions.aggregate(
    [
        {
            $redact: {
                $cond: {
                    if: {
                        $eq: [
                            { $ifNull: [ "$languageId", "en" ] },
                            "en"
                        ]
                    },
                    then: "$$DESCEND",
                    else: "$$PRUNE"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            $addFields: {
                "content": { $arrayElemAt: [ "$content", 0 ] },
                "multipleChoice.possibleAnswers": {
                    $map: {
                        input: "$multipleChoice.possibleAnswers",
                        as: "possibleAnswer",
                        in: {
                            "sequence": "$$possibleAnswer.sequence",
                            "content": { $arrayElemAt: [ "$$possibleAnswer.content", 0 ] }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            $redact: {
                $cond: {
                    if: { $eq: [ "$possibleAnswers", null ] },
                    then: "$$PRUNE",
                    else: "$$DESCEND"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
);
```

Comment: It gives: `InternalError: too much recursion`

Comment: It works for the example you gave. Please tell me more about your schema, what other fields documents can have, how many nested documents etc. Could you also tell me which stage is failing?

Comment: Sorry, I tried it on the example I gave you in Robomongo 1.0, and this was given the error `InternalError: too much recursion`. But now I tried it another way and it works perfectly!! I thank you very much for your time and effort !!

Comment: Do you know some good resources to learn more about the $redact function?

Comment: Well, the official [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact) is pretty good on this topic.

Comment: I went into it and I now understand how it works. It is definitely a nice solution to this problem. The only thing I do not understand is why you need to use `if: { $eq: [ { $ifNull: [ "$languageId", "en" ] }, "en" ] }` instead of `if: { $eq: [ "$languageId", "en" ] }`

Comment: The `$ifNull` is true when a field is null or not existing. We need this operator to "set" the `languageId` for all document levels which do not have it. Without it `$$PRUNE` would be called at the root level of both the input documents (at this level there is no `languageId`), so we would get no results. In fact we "cheat" the `$redact` doing so.